# make: /bin/sh: Command not found

Tags: makefile

**My environment**:

I have recently installed MinGW and GNUWin32 on my Windows 10 pc.

I can compile with g++ successfully without using a make file.

With a makefile, make finds g++ to do compiles.

**Problem**:

My Clean rule is failing with:

```
make: /bin/sh: Command not found
make: *** [clean] Error 127
```

I edited **my makefile** to have only the following:

```
RM = C:\WFF\GNUWin32\bin\rm.exe

clean :
    whoami
    where rm
    ${RM} *.o *.exe
```

When I **execute make**, this is the result:

```
whoami
tilt
where rm
c:\WFF\GNUWin32\bin\rm.exe
C:\WFF\GNUWin32\bin\rm.exe *.o *.exe
make: /bin/sh: Command not found
make: *** [clean] Error 127
```

**Observations**:

`whoami` works
`where` works and finds `rm.exe`

but, through the macro substitution for `${RM}`, `rm.exe` is not found

I tried both of the following with weird results:

1. executed the make file this way: `make SHELL=cmd.exe`
2. added this to the makefile: `SHELL = C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`

For each, make seems to

- call `cmd.exe`
- execute the comand `whoami`
- and stops
- I enter `exit`, and make continues
- call cmd.exe
- execute `where rm`
- and stops
- I enter `exit`, and make continues
- etc.

If I enter `exit` too many times, the window is closed, which doesn't surprise me.

**Question**: any idea what I can do to debug this or solve it?

Comment: Presumably your `SHELL` variable should point to `C:\WFF\GNUWin32\bin\sh.exe` assuming based on other paths seen around.

Comment: My PC is missing sh.exe. I installed MSYS2 and that solved my problem.